# Google analytics is blocked by browser

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, yui2

I want to do some operations if the Google analytics is blocked by the user (may be by the browser).

I am getting a lot of answers here if it is using ga.js, but I am including the analytics.js.

When I tried `(typeof ga) = function` (always irrespective of Google analytics is blocked or not by the browser. But event is not tracked if it is blocked.)

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');       

ga('create', 'google_analytics_id here', 'auto');
```

Any help to track whether you are actually calling the analytics.js.

Thank You

Comment: This is quite possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282313/check-if-analytics-js-is-loaded#comment46762826_29282313

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to see the error message, but try replacing it with this updated version.

```
    (function(b, o, i, l, e, r) {
        b.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l;
        b[l] || (b[l] =
            function() {
                (b[l].q = b[l].q || []).push(arguments)
            });
        b[l].l = +new Date;
        e = o.createElement(i);
        r = o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
        e.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
        r.parentNode.insertBefore(e, r)
    }(window, document, 'script', 'ga'));
    ga('create', 'google_analytics_id here');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Hi Laurentiu, I am not getting any error. If the bowser has blocked the Google analytics access, is there any way to check that we are not going to track anything here using JS?

Comment: @ArunPati, look in the question linked in my comment to your question. There is a function to tell you if a GA tracker is successfully initiated.