# Is there a safe way to check if Google Analytics is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to figure out which is the best way to use google analytics for tracking pageviews and events in a third party javascript widget (not iframe). I know that I can use multiple named trackers, but my problem is, how can I be sure that I only load analytics.js if it's not already loaded on the host page?

I have been looking at solutions like

```
if( window.ga && ga.create ) ...
```

and checking window.GoogleAnalyticsObject and return the analytics object.

But there seems to be problem with both of them. You can't use window.ga because you don't know if the object has a custom name. And from what I read in comments to similar questions the GoogleAnalyticsObject is not guaranteed to be there.

So my question is, is there a 100% safe way to know if the analytics library has already been loaded? Or is using google analytics in third party javascript always a bit insecure? ( I will only use tracking if the owner of the page gives approval )

Comment: Why do you mind if it's already in place on the host page? Adding your own tracker won't affect any trackers already in place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if analytics.js is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282313/check-if-analytics-js-is-loaded)

Comment: I know that I can use multiple trackers, but adding the Google Analytics script when it's already loaded will mess things up @JBrazier